# Is there a way to check for a file with specific name with ros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I have a node that writes data in file and name of that file is "pose.csv". I need to  make sure that every time I start that node it writes data in new file, so result is should be like then I start node first time it loads data in  file "pose_1.csv", than I started it second time the file should be "pose2.csv". Is there a way to achieve this using ros. As far as I know there is no way to check, how many times node has been run, but I could be wrong. Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408587/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-a-file-with-specific-name-with-ros?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-27**:
I am sorry, but this is unrelated to ROS.

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-27**:
Thank you for your reply. I understang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way to check for a file with specific name with ros?

No, this is standard functionality (of the programming language you are using) and is not part of ROS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-27**:
Thank you for your answer.